# Android Crash in RN 0.63.1 Release APK

Tags: react-native, native-base

After updating to RN 0.63.1, the project is running fine in dev but crash in release apk. Is anyone having the same issue? The crash reason and name is as following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
...
```

Was having issues with `<Content>` showing blank space in Native-Base 2.13.12 and updated to 2.13.13 and now they are showing correctly but my release apk is crashing upon start.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I downgraded the Native Base and tried to get the apk. Still having the same issue on release apk.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am also facing crash with react native 0.63.4

Comment: Hello, I just revert back to my previous commit and try all the libraries one by one and it was working again  I think I broke some codes while trying to update.

Comment: Oh I remembered there is one function that is depreacted from Sentry and it was breaking my release apk because the Sentry function is configured to be called only on Production